# Failed to read candidate component class in spring mvc & spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

i add spring boot project as dependency in spring mvc project , application can run successfully but when i call service i faced below error

> Context initialization failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
> to read candidate component class: nested exception is
> org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationConfigurationException:
> Attribute 'proxyBeanMethods' in annotation
> [org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration] is declared as an
> @AliasFor nonexistent attribute 'proxyBeanMethods' in annotation
> [org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration].; nested
> exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
> org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration.proxyBeanMethods()

Answer (score 0):

> Attribute '**proxyBeanMethods**' in annotation
> [org.springframework.boot.**SpringBootConfiguration**] is declared as an
> @AliasFor nonexistent attribute 'proxyBeanMethods' in annotation
> [org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration].; nested
> exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
> org.springframework.context.annotation.**Configuration**.**proxyBeanMethods**()

It mainly complains about your `@Configuration` does not have an attribute called `proxyBeanMethods`. Checking from the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html#proxyBeanMethods--) , this attribute is added since Spring 5.2.

Most probably it is because you are messing up the spring version with your spring-boot version. Your spring version is too old (before 5.2) such that the above attribute of the `@Configuration` is not defined.

You should use the spring framework which the version is defined by the spring-boot version that you use . Show me the `pom.xml` and I can help to check which `<dependency>` causes such version mismatch. Thanks.

Comment: <springVersion>4.3.3.RELEASE</springVersion>

Comment: ok . so revise the spring version accordingly such that to match with spring-boot . first find out the version of your spring-boot. thanks